# SMART Template with a Kendo.Grid() has an error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, templates, kendo-grid

So I'm pretty new at ASP.NET MVC and I'm having an issue I usually don't have when creating listings in Views.

First off: I'm using VS2013 Ultimate and ASP.NET MVC 4.5.1

I'm also using [Kendo.Grid()](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index) and [SMART Template](http://themeforest.net/item/smart-project-management-template/7828254?WT.ac=search_item&WT.oss_phrase=smart&WT.oss_rank=1&WT.z_author=mosaicpro)

When I load my Index View, that has the Kendo.Grid() to show some listing, the Chrome Inspect Element Tool gives me an error, and I'm having some trouble pinpointing it's origin.

The listing is shown perfectly. The error is the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined.

and the file is a jquery file from the template, jquery.flot.js. Has anyone come across this error and solved this?

Comment: i've also tried that my code would run after the document is fully loaded with $( document ).ready(function()

Comment: Are you using that flot plugin on your page, or is it just included in your template file in case you need it? If you are using the flot plugin can you update your question with that piece of code (wrapped in $(document).ready)?

Comment: Also, see if this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flot-graphs/zJaV3cMHQ6c) helps at all

Comment: It's just included in the template, i'm not using it in my page

Comment: Is there any javascript code on the template file that is using the flot plugin that you can see?

Comment: nop, not that i can see.
if there is, it is in the backgroud

Comment: this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flot-graphs/zJaV3cMHQ6c) is similar to my issue